# Когда открываю модель, значение поля автоматически подменяется на другое

Tags: django, django-admin, django-model

Имеется очень тупая проблема: когда открываю модель сотрудника (в админке джанго), значение поля employee_type автоматически подменяется, хотя в БД значение другое. Пример: я создаю сотрудника, выставляю employee_type как "Мененджер", сохраняю. В БД все верно и значение - "Менеджер". Потом открываю этого сотрудника в админке, и значение поля подменяется на "Швея"(Sewer), если на этом этапе сохранить, то Швея будет и в БД.

Я сделал отдельный класс с вариантами значений для данного поля, а также в БД поле определено как enum. Пробовал исследовать этот баг, пришел к выводу, что админка тянет значение не из БД, как должна, а из этого класса с вариантами значений. При этом, тянется всегда именно первое значение из класса.
Никаких функций, которые могли бы подменить значение, я не писал.

К слову, подобные поля я создал в других моделях, но в них все работает корректно и ничего не подменяется.

Как можно это исправить?

Models.py с ошибкой:

```py
class Employee(models.Model):
    class EmployeeType(models.TextChoices):
        SEWER = 'SEWER', _('Sewer')
        MANAGER = 'MANAGER', _('Manager')
        UNDEFINED = 'UNDEFINED', _('Undefined')

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                models.CASCADE,
                                db_column='user',
                                verbose_name=_('User'),
                                primary_key=True)
    employee_type = models.CharField(db_column='Employee type',
                                     verbose_name=_('Employee type'),
                                     max_length=9,
                                     choices=EmployeeType.choices,
                                     default=EmployeeType.UNDEFINED)
    phone = models.CharField(db_column='Phone',
                             verbose_name=_('Phone'),
                             max_length=255)
    work_xp = models.IntegerField(db_column='Work XP',
                                  verbose_name=_('Work XP'),
                                  blank=True,
                                  null=True)
```

Другой models.py, с подобным полями, но без бага:

```py
class Order(models.Model):
    class OrderStatus(models.TextChoices):
        CREATED = 'Created', _('Created')
        CANCELLED = 'Cancelled', _('Cancelled')
        IN_PROGRESS = 'In progress', _('In progress')
        COMPLETED = 'Completed', _('Completed')
        PASSED_TO_CLIENT = 'Passed to the client', _('Passed to the client')
        RETURNED_FOR_REWORK = 'Returned for rework', _('Returned for rework')

    class Urgency(models.TextChoices):
        LOW = 'Low', _('Low urgency')
        MEDIUM = 'Medium', _('Medium urgency')
        HIGH = 'High', _('High urgency')
        VERY_HIGH = 'Very high', _('Very high urgency')

    class LabourIntensity(models.TextChoices):
        LOW = 'Low', _('1-3 days')
        MEDIUM = 'Medium', _('4-6 days')
        HIGH = 'High', _('7-9 days')
        VERY_HIGH = 'Very high', _('10+ days')

    class PaymentStatus(models.TextChoices):
        PENDING = 'Pending payment', _('Pending payment')
        PREPAYMENT_MADE = 'Prepayment made', _('Prepayment made')
        PAID = 'Paid', _('Paid')

    id_service = models.ForeignKey(Service,
                                   models.SET_NULL,
                                   db_column='id_Service',
                                   verbose_name=_('Service'),
                                   blank=True,
                                   null=True)
    status = models.CharField(db_column='Status',
                              verbose_name=_('Status'),
                              max_length=20,
                              choices=OrderStatus.choices,
                              default=OrderStatus.CREATED)
    payment_status = models.CharField(db_column='Payment status',
                                      verbose_name=_('Payment status'),
                                      max_length=15,
                                      choices=PaymentStatus.choices,
                                      blank=True,
                                      null=True)
    prepayment = models.DecimalField(db_column='Prepayment',
                                     verbose_name=_('Prepayment'),
                                     max_digits=19,
                                     decimal_places=2,
                                     blank=True,
                                     null=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(db_column='Cost',
                               verbose_name=_('Cost'),
                               max_digits=19,
                               decimal_places=2,
                               blank=True,
                               null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Start date',
                                      verbose_name=_('Start date'),
                                      blank=True,
                                      null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='End date',
                                    verbose_name=_('End date'),
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)
    id_client = models.ForeignKey(Client,
                                  models.SET_NULL,
                                  db_column='id_Client',
                                  verbose_name=_('Client'),
                                  blank=True,
                                  null=True)
    id_employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee,
                                    models.SET_NULL,
                                    db_column='id_Employee',
                                    verbose_name=_('Employee'),
                                    blank=True,
                                    null=True)
    labour_intensity = models.CharField(db_column='Labour intensity',
                                        verbose_name=_('Labour intensity'),
                                        max_length=9,
                                        choices=LabourIntensity.choices,
                                        default=LabourIntensity.LOW)
    urgency = models.CharField(db_column='Urgency',
                               verbose_name=_('Urgency'),
                               max_length=9,
                               choices=Urgency.choices,
                               default=Urgency.LOW)
    materials = models.ManyToManyField(Material, through='OrderMaterials')
    comment = models.TextField(db_column='Comment',
                               verbose_name=_('Comment'),
                               blank=True,
                               null=True)
```

Comment: наверное не стоит называть поле в модели `id` . Если изменить на `id_employee`. Столбец id создается автоматически при миграции модели. А вы внутри модели указываете еще один с таким же названием

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin поправил как вы посоветовали, баг остался

Comment: миграции тоже сделали?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin да, makemigrations, а затем migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел в чем заключалась проблема.

В БД поле employee_type было определено как:

```sql
ENUM('Undefined','Sewer','Manager')
```

А в модели класс с вариантами содержали такие же значения, но капсом:

```py
class EmployeeType(models.TextChoices):
        SEWER = 'SEWER', _('Sewer')
        MANAGER = 'MANAGER', _('Manager')
        UNDEFINED = 'UNDEFINED', _('Undefined')
```

То есть джанго при сохранении модели передавал в базу значения капсом, а когда обратно загружал значения из БД, не мог сопоставить, потому что в БД совсем другой регистр.

Решение:
Переопределил тип поля в БД как:

```sql
ENUM('UNDEFINED','SEWER','MANAGER')
```

Теперь все работает корректно